# Approximate identities: a converse question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K(x)$ be a positive-valued function such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x)  \ dx = 1$$
and let 
$$K_{\lambda}(x) = \lambda K(\lambda x), \ \ \ (\lambda > 0);$$
that is to say, the family of functions $$\{K_{\lambda}(x)\}, \ \ \  \lambda \uparrow \infty $$
is an approximate identity generated by dilation.

Suppose $f(x)$ is a measurable function, but we do not know in advance whether or not $f(x) \in L^2$. Assume that for every $\lambda > 0$, the function
$$K_{\lambda}(x)*f(x)$$
is finite valued at every $x$.

Further, we know that there exists a function $g(x) \in L^2$ such that
$$ \lim_{\lambda \uparrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [K_{\lambda}(x)*f(x) - g(x)]^{2}  \ dx = 0.$$
Does it follow that $$g(x) = f(x) $$
almost everywhere?

If it makes the question easier to answer, one could add the assumption that $f(x)$ is locally integrable.

Comment: How do we define $K_{\lambda}*f$ if we only know that $f$ is measurable?

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, then the convolution function $K_{\lambda}*f$ is well-defined. I have added the condition that it is finite valued at every $x$.

Comment: If $f$ corresponds to, say, a *bounded distribution* (a continuous linear functional on the class of test functions $\phi$ such that all derivatives of $\phi$ are absolutely integrable), then $K_\lambda * f$ converges to $f$ in the space of bounded distributions, and to $g$ in $L^2$. Thus, $f = g$ almost everywhere. That said, I do not know if it is sufficient to assume that the integrals in the definition of $K_\lambda * f$ are absolutely convergent.